# Learning how to actually draw with HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to learn how to draw to canvas, I read alot of resources it all teachs you about the API and how to use it to draw etc and I found nice resources out there, the problem is now i know how to use the API methods to draw but still I can't figure out how to draw!

Don't get me wrong, I'm not looking forward to learn art concepts etc, I'm talking about simple shapes like a heart or a diamond by example, how do I figure out the coordinates, the `x` and `y` of everything I know how to draw an arc but how do I figure out the control points coordinate by example?

In vector drawing softwares you get visual feedbacks while your drawing and I know its harder and more complicated with canvas, but I don't know what or how I should improve this ability. I don't even know what abilities I have to improve...

Do I have to be good in math?

Can any body direct me to the right way to really learn how to draw to HTML5 Canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being good in math is helpful. Drawing "special" shapes is all about defining them as shapes you already know how to paint. A heart for instance, is 2 arcs with 2 diagonal lines, which I'm sure you know how to draw. A diamond is 4 diagonal lines, where every 2 opposing lines are parallel, and all of them are equal in length.

Comment: thanks , i know how to divide a heart to simple shapes , but what i dont know how to figure out is how do i get the coordinate of each shape ? do i have to draw it on a paper first and measure everything to get the x and y of every shape?

Comment: @Stacker: I think you're too afraid - just try it. If you draw a diamond with a top of `(20, 10)` and another point `(40, 50)`, then you can deduce the other points: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/148/.

Comment: @pimvdb actually it takes 3 points to define a diamond :) (there are infinite diamonds that can be defined with the top and bottom points). But what I mean is, if you draw an arc, 6pi/11 in angle, you can deduce the ending points by using simple math with sin/cos.

Comment: It all depends on how you view and understand it. It's really not that complicated.